# Problems with a big form (50 elements or so) in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I got a pretty big form on a wpf page. I'm putting it together on a Grid, but all the element clutter the page. I figured i'd split out the form into smaller usercontrols and then piece it together on the page as one form. That didn't quite work: [SharedSizeScope on a Grid makes the form 'dance'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827040/sharedsizescope-on-a-wpf-grid-makes-the-form-dance)

I could break up the form into a 'wizard style' page, with a next button - dealing with each user control on its own, but i'd rather not break it up into several pages because the end user is used to having it all on one page. Also the validation/storing of data is really a big-bang operation, making it harder to provide feedback if something goes wrong in one of the first pages/usercontrols.

So what now? I'm really tempted to just put all the small elements directly on the page in one big grid. I just feel it's wrong - it will be a maintenance nightmare - i even started thinking 'i wish there were some kind of #region tag in xaml' - that means i *know* i'm wrong ;)

What can i do?

Comment: What I normally do when I have forms with lots of controls is to arrange them in GroupBoxes or TabItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to use nested container controls, like Grids (or other Panels) inside other Grids inside more Grids etc.

It is very common to have several nesting levels, and thus hierarchically split a complex layout into multiple less complex sub-layouts. This makes your layout significantly simpler compared to one big container that tries to do it all (see your failed ShardSizeScope approach).

Once you have created a sensible hierarchy of containers, you may easily use the Visual Studio XAML editor's code collapsing feature to keep track of all your XAML.

Comment: But how do i keep my page from bloating? You think i should still create a lot of usercontrols (each with its own grid) and put them together on the page in its grid? Woudln't i end up with the same problem of aligning the cells?

Comment: Why UserControls? Simply group few of your elements in a Panel, few other elements in another Panel and so on. Then group those Panels into other Panels again, thus creating a hierarchy of Panels. What do you mean with bloating? Either you need to have all elements in one window/form/page, or not.

Comment: I agree with Clemens, my main application contains about 2000 controls, but grouped in different panels and it's not difficult to maintain

Comment: Ok. I'm sure you're right - i just need to understand. What are the panels for? I mean, if i nest grids then the cell alignment won't work unless i fix size them. I might get away with not aligning vertically outside panels, but each row should be aligned, even across different panels/grids

Comment: Maybe you should provide a sketch or screenshot of what you're going to achieve. If it is simply 50 controls in e.g. a 10 rows x 5 columns grid, then i don't understand the problem.

Comment: I't more like 20 rows with 10 colums and the different rows have different cells spanning 1-8 columns. I think it's a compromise here...

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem with using [Grid.ColumnSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columnspan.aspx) (and perhaps putting some panel for sub-layout in a column-spanned cell).